# Full-search text query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I want to add simple full-search-text to my webapp, that can accept multiple words to search.
Example search entry: "Online SQL books"

Should I transform it to:

```
WHERE (CONTAINS(myColumn,  '"Online*" and "sql*" and "books*"' ))  
or : WHERE (CONTAINS(myColumn,  '"Online* sql* books*"' ))  
or maybe: WHERE (CONTAINS(myColumn,  '"Online*"' ))  and (CONTAINS(myColumn,  '"SQL*"' ))  and (CONTAINS(myColumn,  '"books*"' ))
```

or maybe it's better to use 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL('...

Another question where it's better to construct the query, inside store procedure on inside my business object and then pass it to the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first form is well (CONTAINS(myColumn,  '"Online*" and "sql*" and "books*"' )) - sql anyway spent time to parse query.

Second question is matter of convenience. If you well with string manipulation in sql2005, then do it. But remember on sql-injection problem, so check twice.

Comment: yes sql-injection is important, so what will be safer and faster?

Comment: I think it's best to construct it inside your business object if instead of your stored procedure since you will create additional overhead creating variables and concatenating values etc inside your stored proc (and just generally is not a good practice). Just make sure you sanatize the sql string to avoid sql injection as Dewfy stated.

Comment: @Benjamin&Dewfy, what should I do(or not do) to  prevent sql injection?

Comment: You can start by checking that the string you're passing doesn't contain the ' character, or at least escape it. If you don't you could end-up with someone dropping your entire database depending on security.

Comment: @Benjamin, Is this enough:  content = 
Regex.Replace(content, "[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "").Trim();  
?

Comment: @markiz not agree  the (")-quote is important part of FTS queries, so include it also and check that always has pair

Comment: @Dewfy, I add the (") to string AFTER I do regex replace, first i clear string from none-standard chars and then i weap every word in string with "" and * at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using SQL for full text search is that it can be both very slow and misses searches that you would otherwise want it to succeed on. SQL searching also does not provide any form of ranking to the data so any text containing the terms could end up near the top.

To counter these two problems [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) was created to allow the simple creation of an appropriate word to entries index. In doing so it can also see how frequently words are used within particular entries and provide ranking information. You will find it dramatically outperforms using SQL for the task, both in terms of finding results and execution speed on single searches and especially when scaling to support more searches.